# Using primary key auto increment in url

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i make ecommerce website, if i use primary key auto increment in url for serve products and  sellers and images names, is it safer ?

or generate random and unique string for each products and images names ?

and what is best best method in laravel generate unique string value ?

**Editing :**

for example

http://www.zxc.com/listing/472

472 is product id (primary key auto increment), is it safe or generate unique string for each products ?

thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear, try to rephrase it please.

Comment: No problem, you may use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pk id as to identify a model instance is commonly used. Not so good for SEO though, this is where slugs may help, where you can have an unique id for your products based on a string, for example this package: https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable makes it very easy to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule using Primary Keys in urls is ok for most applications, where the information is publically available and published.

If the url's you're generating are to only be viewed/shared to specific people then you have a problem. Incrementing an integer is **predicable and easy**. In this case it's better to use a unique key, based on a hash.

For example a very very simple example is

```
$key = sha1($primarykey, true);
$url = 'http://www.zxc.com/listing/'.$key;
```

You would obviously need some additional processing on the listings page to parse the id back into an integer but hopefully you get the idea.